# tshark - only output application layer decode

Tags: wireshark, tcp, tshark

Using **tshark**, how would I get it to just decode and display the **application layer**?

For example, I can capture and decode snmp traffic using:

```
sudo tshark -V -i lo -d udp.port==161,snmp
```

This will decode all layers, from the physical layer up to the application layer (output snipped):

```
Frame 120: 134 bytes on wire (1072 bits), ...
    Interface id: 0
    ....
Ethernet II, Src: 00:00:00_00:00:00 (00:00:00...
    Destination: 00:00:00_00:00:00 ...
    ....
Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 127.0.0.1...
    Version: 4
    ....
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: snmp (161), ....
    Source port: snmp (161)
    ....
Simple Network Management Protocol
    version: v2c (1)
    community: public
    ....
```

(I just want the decode from "Simple Network Management Protocol" onwards).

### Other things I've considered

I'm aware of using fields output (eg **-e snmp.community**). Specifying all the fields for snmp would take forever...

I could use pdml output, and transform the results using XSLT. But pdml output is slow and using XSLT seems like overkill:

```
sudo tshark -V -T pdml -i lo -d udp.port==161,snmp

<proto name="udp" showname="User Datagram Protocol...
    <field name="udp.srcport"...
<proto name="snmp" showname="Simple...
    <field name="snmp.version" showname="version: v2c...
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `-O` option, as indicated by the help output:

> `-O <protocols>`           Only show packet details of these protocols, comma separated

```
$ tshark -i 4 -O snmp -q -V > snmp.txt
```

See also the [TShark man-page](http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html):

> `-O` Similar to the `-V` option, but causes TShark to only show a detailed view of the comma-separated list of protocols specified, rather than a detailed view of all protocols. Use the output of "`tshark -G protocols`" to find the abbreviations of the protocols you can specify.

Comment: Please do not reply by editing an answer. You can leave a comment or [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16891706/edit) to include additional details.